# How to hide buttomNavigationBar when move to another page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I create an app with buttomNavigationBar like this to keep the buttomNavigationBar appear when move to another page, this code is on layout.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onWillPop, // prevent click back on device
      child: new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: background(),
        body: Stack(
          children: List<Widget>.generate(4, (int index) {
            return IgnorePointer(
              ignoring: index != _pageIndex,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: _pageIndex == index ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                child: Navigator(
                  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                    return new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => _page(index),
                      settings: settings,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),

        bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar() // my navigation bar
      )

    );
  }

Widget _page(int index) { // get index from navigation bar
    switch (index) {
      case 0: return Home();
      case 1: return Store();
      case 2: return Message();
      case 3: return Account();
    }

    throw toast('Invalid index $index');
  }
```

So, in page Account I have a button which if clicked will display register page, and I need to hide the bottomNavigationBar, I have been try like this

in main.dart

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/register': (context) => new Register(),
      },
```

then I call it like this on press button, but it does not work

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
```

How to solve this problem? thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Move the Scaffold further down the tree, so it appears in each Page, ie Home, Store, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a variable at the top `bool _showBottomNavigation;`.
2. Change its value in `build` method if the widget is stateless or `initState` if the widget is stateful.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   bool _showBottomNavigation = true;
   ...
}
```

3. Show bottom navigation bar based on the variable

```
bottomNavigationBar: _showBottomNavigation ? _bottomNavigationBar() : Container()
```

4. Change the variable value before navigating to the other page

```
_showBottomNavigation = false;
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
```